# Deterministically combining generators

Tags: javascript, generator

I have a javascript project where I need to be able to create deterministic generators (I call them `Arbitrary`s). For instance, I can create a arbitrary username using the following code:

```
const name = arb.oneOf('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz');
```

This results in a generator that yields the 3 values in turn, and then exits. However, I also have a function witch creates tuples from multiple arbitrary instances, like this:

```
const namePairs = arb.tuple(name, name);
```

This would spit out things like `['Foo', 'Foo']`, `['Foo', 'Bar']`, etc. It's still doing so deterministically, so that whenever I iterate through the `namePairs` generator, I always get the same values. However, the algorithm I've written to achieve this is not really good. It has a few bad features, such that it does not generate all possible combinations, and it can in some cases emit the same value twice. This isn't too big of a problem, but I'd like to improve it, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Basically, what I need is a function that takes a variable number of generators which (can) have different lengths and return a single generator that has the following properties:

1. It's deterministic. If I create multiple of the same arbitrary instance, from the same "child" arbitrary instances, I should always get the same items.
2. It evenly distributes the number of items it grabs from the child generators. This is important, because the total possible number of items a generator can produce is normally way bigger than the number of items I actually request. Therefore, it's important that if I do `arb.tuple(allPositiveNumbers, allPositiveNumbers)` I don't just get `1` as the first argument, and increasing numbers as the second (or the other way around).
3. If possible I would like it to exhaustively produce all possible combinations of the input generators without producing duplicates. This is less of a requirement and more of a wish though.

Any hint on how to make something like this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you give an example of what the first few outputs of `arb.tuble(allPositiveNumbers, allPositiveNumbers)` should give? I'm trying to wrap my head around the problem.

Comment: Basically, you want to recode how computer generate random values. And be able to use the input as "seed" so matching inputs produce the same number sequence ?

Comment: @MikeC what I have currently would give me `[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]`, which is fine, but the best would probably be something like: `[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 3]` or something similar.

Comment: This would take "infinite" memory though, but that's not a problem because I only ever ask for 100 values at the maximum.